# New VS Code update made tab drag-and-drop snappy

Tags: visual-studio-code

It seems like the new VS Code update made the drag-and-drop behavior of tabs snappy (with the white vertical bar) instead of smooth. Is it a way to revert the changes? Or maybe some setting we can adjust?

Edit: By smooth I mean that the other tabs will slide left and right when hovering the dragged tab over them. By snappy I mean that the white vertical bar snaps in place between tabs.

[image]

Comment: It was never smooth for me, but the highlight was different (it highlighted the whole tab to the left of which we're inserting).

Comment: can you elaborate? what do you mean by "snappy" and "smooth"?

Comment: By smooth I mean that the other tabs will slide left and right when hovering the dragged tab over them. By snappy I mean that the white vertical bar snaps in place between tabs. I will update the question!